# Logger with reload duplicate logs printing

Tags: python, logging

I have a logger in `afile.py` file, with this configuration:

```
logcurrent = logging.getLogger("app")
logcurrent.setLevel(logging.INFO)
formatter = logging.Formatter(
    '%(message)s',
    '%d-%m-%Y %I:%M:%S',
)
file_handlerCurrent = logging.handlers.WatchedFileHandler(
    '/var/log/app.log'
)
file_handlerCurrent.setLevel(logging.INFO)
file_handlerCurrent.setFormatter(formatter)
logcurrent.addHandler(file_handlerCurrent)
```

in `bfile.py`, I use to reload this file again:

```
reload(afile)
```

Every time the reload executed, a file handler is added, and my log is printed many time.

How can I avoid it? Is there any way to get the list of the handler and remove some?

Comment: Is that done at the top level of the module? Put the setup in a function and only call it once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to both get and modify the list of used handlers. `logcurrent.handlers` is a `list` of used handlers, and deleting a handler from this list removes it from the logger as well.

You could initialize your logger somewhat like this:

```
logcurrent = logging.getLogger("app")
if not logcurrent.hasHandlers():
    logcurrent.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    formatter = logging.Formatter(
        '%(message)s',
        '%d-%m-%Y %I:%M:%S',
    )
    file_handlerCurrent = logging.handlers.WatchedFileHandler(
        '/var/log/app.log'
    )
    file_handlerCurrent.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    file_handlerCurrent.setFormatter(formatter)
    logcurrent.addHandler(file_handlerCurrent)

def change_all_handlers_to(handler):
    logcurrent.handlers = []
    logcurrent.addHandler(handler)

def remove_first_handler():
    if logcurrent.hasHandlers():
        del logcurrent.handlers[0]
```

---

### Edit

The method `logger.hasHandlers()` is [new in Python 3.2](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.hasHandlers), if you are using Python 2 you'll have to fall back to [`logger.handlers`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/logging/__init__.py#l1134) for checking if the logger has been initialized. But `Boolean([]) == False`, so you can ask for the list directly.

Mind, though, that `logger.handlers` is no part of the 'official API' (it doesn't show [in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/logging.html#logger-objects)), neither for Python 2 nor 3, so it might *possibly* change without notice.